# OpenStack4j - Is there a method for getting temporary url for object in store object?

Tags: java, openstack

I am doing an integration with object storage using OpenStack4j. I want to generate a temporary url for the file.

I found in the documentation how to do it myself, but I wonder if there is a method in OpenStack4j API that gives me an url for specific SwiftObject.

Thanks!